# Converting a Get/Set class into a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, class, service-reference

I have a class:

```
namespace BugNETLibrary
{
    public class NewUser
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int UserRole { get; set; }
        public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert this class into a WCF Service that I can reference in my project.

I have at the minute an interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface INewUser
    {
        string UserName { get; set; }
        int UserRole { get; set; }
        string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    }


[DataContract]
public class GetNewUser
{
    string userName;
    int userRole;
    string loweredUserName;

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int UserRole
    {
        get { return userRole; }
        set { userRole = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string LoweredUserName
    {
        get { return loweredUserName; }
        set { loweredUserName = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if even this is correct but i am not sure what to add to the service class that inherits the interface so all I have is

```
public class NewUser : INewUser
    {

    }
```

Can somebody help me with what needs doing next? I'm sure I have done something wrong already but I am not sure what. Is this actually possible?

Comment: I don't know if you are not clear about something or you did not read about WCF. You can read this easy example: http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: At a glance, you need to have methods in your interface and decorate them with the `[OperationContract]` attribute.  Also, a DataContract is used for serializing data over the wire - your service methods should take `NewUser` as an input and/or return it as a result.  You'll implement the method in the interface in the `NewUser` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services expose methods (Operation Contracts) to the client.  Your interface doesn't have any methods, so there's nothing to implement (from a service perspective).

You could do something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INewUser
{
    [OperationContract]
    UserInfo CreateNewUser(string userName);
}
```

Then in the implementing class, you'd have:

```
public NewUser : INewUser
{

    public UserInfo CreateNewUser(string userName)
    {

        return new UserInfo() {
                   UserName = "John Doe",
                   UserRole = 5,
                   LoweredUserName = "john doe"
                   };
    }
}
```

`UserInfo` would be the class used to represent the info, per your original code, marked as a data contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserInfo
{

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int UserRole { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
}
```

This is a trivial example based on your above code, to show you how it can all go together.

**HOWEVER**

What you really should do is look at your existing library, wrap the *functionality* in a WCF service, and mark the `NewUser` class up as a data contract.  It looks like you're focusing on the data, and you should first focus on the functionality.

Put another way, what methods in your current library **use** `NewUser`, as either inputs or return types - that is what goes into the service, not the properties of the `NewUser` class.